# Anti-aliased(smooth) line using andengine GLES20

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

How can i draw anti-aliased(smooth) line using andengine GLES20 ?
I can draw only ugly line.

Comment: Have you tried to enable multisample or increase the line width? But note that, line width support is depended on devices.

Comment: @正宗白布鞋 what you talk about multisample? please elaborate more on this because rotated sprite also got same problem.

Comment: YourEngineOption.getRenderOptions().getConfigChooseOptions().setRequestedMultiSampling(true).  This is the usage in GLES2-AC branch, if you're on GLES2, it is similar, but a little different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem using images with lines.

Answer (score 0):

in openGL ES2, try the following settings by overriding the onCreateEngineOptions() in your activity class which extends SimpleBaseGameActivity or its sub/super class.

```
@Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        init();

        Camera camera = createCamera();

        IResolutionPolicy policy = ResolutionPolicy.createResolutionPolicy(mEngineConfig.getResolutionPolicy(), mEngineConfig.getScreenWidth(), mEngineConfig.getScreenHeight());

        EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(mEngineConfig.getFullScreen(), mEngineConfig.getScreenOrientation().getValue(), policy, camera);

        options.getRenderOptions().setMultiSampling(true);
            //... MORE OPTIONS

        return options;
    }
```